# Can a base class implement an explicit interface?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, multiple-inheritance

A snippet can speak more than a thousand words. Is there a way to make the following work, if not, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ISquealer
{
public:
    virtual void squeale() = 0;
};

class DefaultSqueel : public ISquealer // May be others
{
public:
    virtual void squeale() override
    {
        std::cout << "Squeeaale!!";
    }
};

class IAnimal : public ISquealer
{
public:
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class Pig : public IAnimal, public DefaultSqueel
{
public:
    virtual std::string getName() { return "Piggy"; }
};


int main()
{
    Pig pig; // object of abstract type 'Pig' is not allowed
}
```

Edit:

Just to clarify what's wrong: This does not compile as the compiler thinks that Pig is abstract and thus cannot be instantiated even though the squeale method is actually implemented inside of the Pig inheritence hierarchy.

Comment: You don't say what it should be doing when its working.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? The snippet is broken so there is no way "to make it work" when you dont say what it is supposed to do

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit to clarify. The error is that 'Pig' is abstract when I would assume that the abstract method would be implemented by the DefaultSqueel base class. I wonder why that is and how I can fix it.

Comment: is it on purpose that `squeale()` is private in `DefaultSqueel` ?

Comment: @tobi303 no, that's an error. Doesn't seem to make a difference though.

Comment: of course it makes a difference, if it is private you cannot get acces without modifiying `DefaultSqueel`

Comment: @tobi303 sure, but it doesn't make the compiler happier in this case. I edited the sample. :)

Answer (score 2):

`IAnimal` doesn't override the virtual `squeale` function.

So even though `Pig` inherits from `DefaultSqueel`, the compiler is not satisfied that the `IAnimal` part of it that is inherited is not still virtual.

If, rather, `Pig` had overrided the `squeale` function then it would have compiled:

```
class Pig : public IAnimal, public DefaultSqueel
{
    virtual std::string getName() { return "Piggy"; }
    virtual void squeale() override
    {
        DefaultSqueel::squeale() ; //to avoid reimplementing
    }
};
```

If you look at the inheritance diagram then it seems clear that there is no benefit to inheriting from `ISquealer` twice:

[image]

If there is only a single inheritance from `ISquealer` then the code also compiles:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ISquealer
{
public:
    virtual void squeale() = 0;
};

class DefaultSqueel : public ISquealer // May be others
{
    virtual void squeale() override
    {
        std::cout << "Squeeaale!!";
    }
};

class IAnimal 
{
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class Pig : public IAnimal, public DefaultSqueel
{
    virtual std::string getName() { return "Piggy"; }
};


int main()
{
    Pig pig; // object of abstract type 'Pig' is not allowed
}
```

Comment: hmm, yes, but then I would have a ISqueale implementation in Pig, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Remove inheritance of IAnimal from ISqueale - it is different interface with different set of functions... or call DefaultSqueel::squeale() from Pig::squeale()